# How to make dictionary from this list with regexes?

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary

I need to do something like this with regex:

```
'host': '146.204.224.152',
'user_name': 'feest6811',
'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700',
'request': 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1'
```

I already have the four lists:

```
host = re.findall("(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})",logdata)
user_name = re.findall("[a-z]{1,100}\d{4}\ ", logdata) 
time = re.findall("\d{2}/[A-z]{3}/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} -\d{4}", logdata)
request = re.findall("[A-Z]{1,30}\ /[\w/+]{1,100} [HTTP/]{5}\d{1}\.\d{1}", logdata)
```

And then tried to make a dictionary in this way:

```
result = {'host': host, 'user_name': user_name, 'time': time, 'request': request}
```

But I got this:

```
'host': ['146.204.224.152',
  '197.109.77.178',
  '156.127.178.177',
  '100.32.205.59',
  '168.95.156.240',
  '71.172.239.195',
  '180.95.121.94',
  '144.23.247.108',
  '2.179.103.97',
  '241.114.184.133',
...]
'user_name': ['feest6811 ',
  'kertzmann3129 ',
  'okuneva5222 ',
  'ortiz8891 ',
  'stark2413 ',
  'dooley1853 ',
  'mohr6893 ',
  'auer7552 ',
  'lind8584 ',
  'tromp8355 ',
  'keebler1423 ',
  'klein8508 ',
  'gusikowski9864 ',
  'medhurst2732 ',
  'dubuque8645 ',
...]
```

and so on with the other varibles. How can I make it as the example?

Comment: You are using re.findall per variable which will get all the results per pattern. You could create a single pattern with 4 capturing groups instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through your `findall` results in parallel.  What you did was to make one large dict entry containing the entire lists.

```
elist = []    # short for entry list
for ehost, euser, etime, ereq in zip(host, user_name, time, request):
    elist.append(
        {"host": ehost,
         "user_name": ename,
         "time": etime,
         "request": ereq
        }
```

Perhaps more to your comfort level would be to use a common index, and pull each corresponding value out of each list:

```
for i in range(len(host)):
    elist.append(
        {"host": host[i],
         "user_name": user_name[i],
         "time": time[i],
         "request": req[i]
        }
```